# Android Device act as Client FAT32 mass storage to Windows Host

Tags: android, usb, fat32, scsi, usb-mass-storage

Is it possible to make an android application that would allow for a computer running windows to be connected to the Android via USB and for the Windows machine to believe that the android is a FAT32 storage device?

What I know so far:
1. The Android application would need to emulate SCSI protocol
2. The android application would need to emulate the FAT32 file system

Can an android application capture the USB interface to emulate being a storage device?

From initial testing, the Android USB driver / operating system is handling the initial communications on the device before handing off to the application. This is causing problems as to make this work I believe I need to send the original signal to inform the host that communication will be done using SCSI.
Additional problems are that it appears as though I need to add the host's vendor id to the application before I am allowed to act as a client. This will be a problem as I don't have that information in all cases and requiring a user to input it would not be a good experience.

I don’t need to expose the file system of the android. Instead, the files that would be exposed to the Host (windows machine) would be custom and would not be stored on the phone.
To be clear in this case, the Host would be the windows machine the client would be the android device. The Android device would need to act as a mass storage device. An application would be the one simulating the storage interface and exposing a custom file system designed for the host.